# Kendo UI Routing Issue SPA

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, single-page-application

I'm trying to create single page UI with router function but when I run the code UI gets redirected to base URI Instead of staying on routed URI.
I have uploaded my code on [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/Shridhar099/bWE6R/5/)

```
$(function() {
    router.start();
    $("#showHome").click(function (){
        alert('showHome click');
        history.back();
        router.navigate("/");
        return false;
    });

    $("#showSales").click(function (){
        alert('showSales click');
        history.back();
        router.navigate("/mycars");
        return false;
    });

    $("#showAboutme").click(function (){
        alert('showAboutme click');
        history.back();
        router.navigate("/aboutme");
        return false;
    });

    });
```

any help would be appreciated. - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are being redirected to base URI because of your links are using "#" in the href attribute:

```
<li><a id="showHome" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="showSales" href="#">Sale Chart</a></li>
<li><a id="showAboutme" href="#">About me</a></li>
```

You should replace those for the actual route:

```
<li><a id="showHome" href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="showSales" href="/mycars">Sale Chart</a></li>
<li><a id="showAboutme" href="/aboutme">About me</a></li>
```